# How to get one row for the each individual name for the last date in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
("Name 1", "2018-07-25", 14),
("Name 2", "2018-08-04", 88),
("Name 3", "2018-08-15", 18),
("Name 2", "2018-06-24", 20),
("Name 2", "2018-09-10", 77),
("Name 2", "2018-08-01", 39),
("Name 1", "2018-07-10", 58),
("Name 1", "2018-06-22", 19),
("Name 3", "2018-09-03", 27),
("Name 1", "2018-09-25", 12)],
columns=["Name", "Date", "Numbers"])
```

[image: Initial table]

I need to get one row of each individual name for the last date. To get the table like this:

[image: resulted table]

Rows to be moved to the new table are highlighted in yellow (in the first table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first convert date it in `Date` format

[`pd.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `Name and Date`

[`pd.drop duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by `Name`

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df.sort_values(['Name','Date'],ascending=[False,False],inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(['Name'],inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
    Name       Date     Numbers
8  Name 3  2018-09-03       27
4  Name 2  2018-09-10       77
9  Name 1  2018-09-25       12
```

Answer (score 1):

you can group on `Name` and transform `max` on `Date` column and compare:

```
df[df['Date'].eq(df.groupby('Name')['Date'].transform('max'))] #.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
     Name        Date  Numbers
4  Name 2  2018-09-10       77
8  Name 3  2018-09-03       27
9  Name 1  2018-09-25       12
```